# how can i make light pass through an object in blender? (V. 2.92)

Tags: light

i want to make a sun, but wen i put the light point on it, the light don't come out of the mesh.

before:
[image]

after:
[image]

what i can do?

Answer (score 1):

You should increase the radius of your point light until it's the size of your star (which will produce more realistic shadows) and then increase the shadow's clip start to make sure the star's surface doesn't occlude any light, but not too much so that other objects can cast shadows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you man! :)